# Flutter: Is There a way to identify if the context has the required provider or if context has MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I have situation where i am using `.of(context)` in a function to get the Scoped Object data and use it. However this function is sometimes invoked with a context that does not provide the required context and so it cannot be used and takes default value.

What i am trying to do is to check if the given say MediaQuery is scoped in the context and do something else rather than use default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can find the widget or data is in the ancestor of the context by using this method.

```
context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<T>() != null
```

for example to check if Media Query Data is in the passed context
`context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() != null`

If this check returns true then we have MediaQueryData available in the context passed.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the context use with

```
if(mounted){
//your code
}
```

this checks if the context is valid to use.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html

Comment: Right answer! 

Solved it by condition:
if (my_context.mounted == true) ...